# Problema para realizar conexion con base de datos de oracle en una maquina virtual

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, virtualbox, windows-server, oracle-12c

Tengo un problema con la conexión a una base de datos ubicada en una maquina virtual, la maquina virtual se encuentra con Windows server 2019, y la base de datos de Oracle es la 12c, y el software de SQL Developer se encuentra en una maquina física(la cual se intenta hacer la conexión). la maquina virtual se encuentra corriendo con virtual Box, ambas maquinas se encuentran conectadas por adaptador puente, y configuradas en el mismo grupo de trabajo. Ambas maquinas poseen una conexión ya que se recibe respuesta al momento de hacer ping de una a otra...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los posibles problemas que pienso que puede estar afectando es:

- Por parte de los sistemas operativos no se encuentran bien configurados.
- Por parte del virtual box que no se encuentra bien configurado el adaptador, ya que es lo que se especifica en el error.
- Los datos ingresados en el SQL developer están mal **(cabe destacar que los datos de autenticación si se encuentran bien ingresados)**

Comment: Primero realiza un ping de tu maquina anfitrion a la maquina virtual, esto para descartar el adaptador virtual, si si te responde ahora deshabilita el firewall de la maquina virtual

Comment: ¿Cuál SO tiene el anfitrión de VirtualBox? El host ¿tiene mas de una tarjeta de red? ¿Es Oracle XE?

Comment: @Sal, si correcto es Oracle XE, solo una tarjeta de red, y el sistema operativo es windows 10 Pro, y la maquina virtual Windows Server 2019

Comment: @SaulEspinoza, ambas maquinas esta verificadas su conexión por medio de ping y ambos maquinas tienen el firewall deshabilitado

Comment: Con una sola tarjeta no funcionará por puente, agrega otra o cambia el modo de red, ¿a cuál? depende mucho del contexto de uso. Hasta donde recuerdo el sid en la conexión debe ser XE.